# Error :sys/types.h No such directory found

Tags: c, ubuntu

[image]

I am working in Ubuntu and I want to include types.h file in my source. I have tried including `#include <linux/types.h>` as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589407/kernel-module-build-fails-sys-types-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
but this doesn't seem to work, I also tried this command `sudo apt-get install build-essential` as mentioned [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1922575) which didn't work either.  Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get install build-essential flex libelf-dev libc6-dev-amd64 binutils-dev libdwarf-dev`

Comment: How did installing `build-essential` fail?  That is the root cause for any other problems you are having.

Comment: @Haris that didnt help

Comment: @tripleee it didn't fail, i didn't help resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Files `sys/types.h` are provided by packages libc6-dev:amd64 and libc6-dev-i386